# Problem Creating Site Collection

Tags: site-template, site-collection

We are getting this error when attempting to create new sitecollections based on our sitedefinition. Any ideas of what can be wrong?

Successfully applied template "STCommunitySite#0" to web at URL `http://weekly-community.company.com/sites/s`.

Leaving Monitored Scope (Applying Named Web Template: STCommunitySite#0). Execution Time=78383.6786518957

GetUriScheme(_fields/resources/_fields.en-US.resx)

Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.

Exception attempting to ApplyWebTemplate to SPSite `http://weekly-community.company.com/sites/s`:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.  Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.set_SchemaXml(String value)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.FixFieldsFromColumnTemplate()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SyncNewLists()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPSiteAdministration siteAdministration, String strWebTemplate, String strRedirect, Boolean bCreateDefaultGroups, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) Attempting to delete the site collection.
```

Comment: Very unconstructive: use custom web templates instead of custom site definitions! ;-) More constructive: please add more relevant lines from ULS

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't find any more relevant ULS lines. I belive it is a call to GetUriScheme that is failing. This only happens in one of our environments. The working environments continue after GetUriScheme(_fields/resources/_fields.en-US.resx) with GetUriScheme(/sites/s/Lists/CommunityCalendar). I will look into using custom web templates in future scenarios, I am just wondering how they are to maintain if you want to make changes to your solution after first production?

Comment: that's the dark side of the SharePoint... errors are often very low meaningful. In general, when I work with site templates, I try to put everything in features. This allows me to debug features by feature. Finally, my custom site definition only references my features.

Comment: see thats the beauty of it: since Web Templates are a "fire and forget" manifest, you can change anything you like, unlike with site definitions where ALL changes are UNSUPPORTED after the first deployment

Comment: if you cannot add more relevant information i will probably have to close Q as too localized. There really isnt much information to go on here...

Comment: Np, just close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was related to the creation of a custom list. Most likely error in schema. For now it is commented out.